# How do I use a specific port when connecting to a time server with timedatectl

Tags: 16.04, time, ntp

I'm trying to connect to a time server with timedatectl. I have enabled ntp with timedatectl. I can ping ntp.ubuntu.com.

I then attempted

```
timedatectl -H ntp.ubuntu.com
```

but got a message saying that it failed to query the host. After a few minutes pass I'll get a message saying "ssh: connect to host ntp.ubuntu.com port 22: network is unreachable"

I then performed a

```
telnet ntp.ubuntu.com 22
```

and it failed to connect. I then performed a

```
telnet ntp.ubuntu.com 80
```

and I get the response:

```
connected to 91.189.94.1
conected to ntp.ubuntu.com
connection closed by foreign host
```

I assume that I need to perform the "timedatectl -H ntp.ubuntu.com" command with a port. The instructions says

```
"Specify a hostname, or a username and hostname separated by "@", to connect to. The hostname may optionally be suffixed by a port ssh is listening on, seperated by ":", and then a container name, separated by "/", which connects directly to a specific container on the specified host."
```

I tried this but it did not work

```
timedatectl -H 80:ntp.ubuntu.com
timedatectl -H ntp.ubuntu.com:80
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: AFAIK `timedatectl -H` expects to communicate via SSH - I doubt you can use an open port that is running a different service. Is an SSH server actually running on the ntp host, and if so on what port?